# How does this recursive function breaks and returns

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I am new to coding and am confused as to how this reverse function returns the string. I thought it would be an infinite loop. I know that when `isEmpty()` is `true` it breaks but why would `sentence.isEmpty()` be `true`?

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "Papa Jhon";
    String reversed = reverse(sentence);
    System.out.println("The reversed sentence is: " + reversed);
  }

  public static String reverse(String sentence) {
    if (sentence.isEmpty())
      return sentence;

    return reverse(sentence.substring(1)) + sentence.charAt(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: `reverse(sentence.substring(1))` will make the string shorter every time. Eventually it becomes empty.

Comment: `sentence.substring(1)` returns a substring starting from index `1` until the end of the string, for `"Papa Jhon"` this would yield `"apa Jhon"`, which is then passed again into the function as the new `sentence` parameter. This continues until `sentence="n"` where `sentence.substring(1)` will then return the empty string `""`

Comment: "I thought it would be an infinite loop" - You probably have a misconception here. Would you like to explain why you came to that conclusion, i.e. why you thought `isEmpty()` could never return `true`? That way we could help remove the misconception :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.

> [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.

Calls to `String.substring(1)` will return a `String` with length `String.length()-1`, eventually decreasing the length of the returned `String` to zero. This, in turn, triggers `String.isEmpty()`.